# Why wouldn't this change the values in the array?

Tags: c

I know in C, things are passed by value however I thought that arrays, if modified in functions (without making a copy) would have the original modified but when I run this code that does not happen. I am assuming range doesn't change len because of the scope?

Can someone explain?

```
static void task(int *b, int range){
  b[range-1] = 200;
  range = 0;
  b = NULL;
}

int main (){
  int a[]= {2,4,6};
  int len = 3, i;
  printf("len1:  %d\n", len);

  task(a,len);
  printf("len %d\n", len);
  for(i=0; i < len; i++){
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*it does not happen*"? What exactly? After the call to `task()`, `a` contains `{2, 4, 200}`. `range = 0` and `b = NULL` are essentially no-ops, however, because you are modifying local variables (copies of the call parameters).

Comment: `len` won't change unless u call `task(a, &len)` and declare `task(int *b, int* range)`. In your example `len` doesn't change because it's passed by value and not by reference.

Comment: Don't modifications to arrays within functions change the original array?

Comment: Yes, but `len` passed as `range` is not an array, so it's passed by value like everything else. Nor does modifying the locally scoped pointer argument modify the pointer that was originally passed. Only arrays (which effectively decay to pointers) or the _targets_ of pointers can be modified within a function in a way that escapes to the outside scope.

Comment: `static void task(int *b, int range){` Is it allowed to make a function static?

Comment: @sun, yes.  A `static` function in C is local to that file, cannot be accessed from another file (or "translation unit", to be pedantic).

Comment: Actually you cannot pass an array to a function - as an array. Instead the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first entry - that's why `int *b` as argument works (a pointer is not an array!). So, there is really no exception to the pass by value principle.

Comment: @SamWatkins: To use the precise term: it has internal linkage, like other `static` objects are file-level.

Comment: @SamWatkins Yes, I misremembered the sentense "The declarations in the declaration list shall contain no storage-class specifier other than register and no initializations." in N1570

Comment: C passes scalar arguments by value, but arrays are in effect passed by reference, since rather than passing the array, C instead passes the address of the first element of the array.  So if you modify a scalar argument, it has no effect on the caller, but if you modify an array argument, you are in fact writing through a pointer argument and the result is visible to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

When using pointers, you can modify to what the pointer is pointing to, but not the pointer itself.
So, your function will modify a, effectively putting 200 in the last position, however, it will not become NULL.
Len wont be modified as well.
To modify both of them, you should do

```
void task(int **b, int *range) {
    *(b)[*range - 1] = 200;
    *range = 0;
    *b = NULL;
}
```

And call it as

```
task(&b, &len);
```

But why would you want to modify the array if you are gonna set it to NULL later?

Comment: This is a code snippet from a quiz review to emphasize concepts we've learned I didn't write this

Comment: "to emphasize concepts we've learned" are they trying to teach you how to write no-ops? what was their actual question?

Comment: That explain why is that weird

Comment: Downvoted: You cannot set array to NULL, it's not a pointer. Besides array already decays to pointer, there is no reason for double pointer nonsense.

Comment: It is not the fault of the function, but how he declares b

Comment: This example is incorrect.  If called as shown, the argument `b` as seen by `task` is *not* an `int **`.  It is in fact an `int (*)[3]`, and its value is the address of `a`.  It is not an array of pointers, as your example expects.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you declare the array `int a[]= {2,4,6};` is that the values `2,4,6` will be stored in memory in three consecutive memory fields. In variable `a` will be stored the address to the first memory field (where the first array element was saved).

When calling `task(a,len);` you pass a copy of this address (call by value).
Because of this you can enter the array in the called function but can not override the actual variable `a`.

What happens there is that `b[range-1] = 200;` overrides the third element with `200`. `range = 0;` and `b = NULL;` do only override the local variables, that only exist in the function. The least two instructions don't affect the variables in your `main()`.

When returning to `main()` `a` and `len` have still the same values as before calling `task(a,len);`. But the values stored in the array are now `a={2,4,200};`.